# Use Laravel Carbon class in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How can I use Carbon class in laravel blade template??

```
<td class="uppercase">{{ Carbon::createFromTimeString($data->time)->format('g:i a')  }}</td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As blade don't have import system to `use Carbon\Carbon` import like that
you have to use `Carbon\Carbon::` in blade

```php
<td class="uppercase">{{ Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeString($data->time)->format('g:i a')  }}</td>
```

ref links

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-format-a-carbon-date-inside-blade?page=1

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

---

and best approach is use laravel [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

in your model

```php
public function getTimeFormatedAttribute()
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeString($this->time)->format('g:i a')
}
```

then in blade you can

```php
<td class="uppercase">{{ $data->time_formated }}</td>
```